# What is wrong with this INTERVAL syntax in my PHP MYSQL code?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to get the database to update when INTERVAL is set

```
$update_query="UPDATE subscriber SET txn_type='$txn_type', expire_date=(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH), subscription_type='$item_name', last_payment = NOW(), subscr_id ='$subscr_id', txnid = '$txn_id', payment_status='paid' WHERE id= '$id'";
```

But w/o INTERVAL it works fine

```
$update_query="UPDATE subscriber SET txn_type='$txn_type', expire_date=CURDATE(), subscription_type='$item_name', last_payment = NOW(), subscr_id ='$subscr_id', txnid = '$txn_id', payment_status='paid' WHERE id= '$id'";
```

Everywhere I look, this seems to be the correct way to set interval. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean to add 1 month:

```
expire_date= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  expire_date=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```